# Neovim not respecting invocation name: view, vimdiff, etc

Tags: neovim

`Vim` (v8, but I think [nearly] all versions) has different behavior depending on its invocation name:

- `view` => `vim -R`
- `vimdiff` => `vim -d`

Neovim does *not* respect invocation name by changing functionality.

I've configured my `nvim` alternates as outlined on the Neovim [installation page](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Installing-Neovim)
The fact that those alternatives exist implies that Neovim would pay attention to its invocation name.

Do I need to set something in my neovim config so that it changes behavior based on invocation name?

Answer (score 1):

> Note, however, that special interfaces, like view for nvim -R, are not supported. (See #1646 and #2008.)

From the section on `update-alternates`.

Comment: That's unfortunate. It seems #2008 breaks their vision of "In matters of taste/ambiguity, favor tradition/compatibility..." I support *many* users who use "vim" & its invocation alternatives. I have reams of documentation which make reference to said invocations. I don't fancy building/maintaining a layer above nvim to mitigate these changes. No one is forced to create an "alias" (symlink, hard link, alt) called "view" for "vim -R" but stripping invocation detection from nvim seems short sighted.

Comment: Is there a way to script nvim (in `init.vim`) to detect its invocation name and switch modes?

Comment: …so why use NeoVim @LiamF if it won't meet your needs? You could probably do something with `v:argv[0]` or `v:progpath`, but note that `readonly` is buffer-local whereas with `vim -R`/`view`, it's set for all buffers (but you might be able to `set readonly` and have it propagate…). Emulating `vimdiff` would be harder, since you'd have to process the rest of `v:argv` to get the layout right (checking for `-o`/`diffopt`/etc.)

Comment: Good question and one I'm asking myself. Unfortunately, I'm not sure I can change course easily at this point. Everyone has come to enjoy the features/plugins that make neovim standout. For now, I've placed a layer above neovim (PATH trickery and bash stubs) that will take care of the problem *for now* and keep the complaints to a minimum. I need more coffee for a better solution. Thanks for your help!